# How to fix legend order using ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggnewscale

I am creating a plot that has 2 legends using both `ggplot2` and `ggnewscale`. What I'm trying to achieve is to fix the order of the separate legends so they always appear in the same order. The images and code below show a basic example of the issue I'm having.

First, create some data and set the colour palettes:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = runif(10))
df_1 <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = runif(10))

pal_1 = rev(colorspace::sequential_hcl(palette = "Blues 3", n = 10))
pal_2 = rev(colorspace::sequential_hcl(palette = "Reds 3", n = 10))
```

Now create a plot (note the limits I set are between 0 and 1 for the legends):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(df, mapping = aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, aes(fill = y)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = pal_1, limits = c(0,1), name = "val1") +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_point(data = df_1, size = 3, aes(fill = y)) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colors = pal_2, limits = c(0,1), name = "val2")
```

This will result in the following image (note that the legend for `val1` is on the top):

[image: plot 1]

Now, if we change the limits for `val2` to something larger, like so:

```
ggplot(df, mapping = aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, aes(fill = y)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = pal_1, limits = c(0,1), name = "val1") +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_point(data = df_1, size = 3, aes(fill = y)) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colors = pal_2, limits = c(0,10), name = "val2")
```

We will get this (note that `val2` legend is now on top:

[image: plot 2]

It seems that `ggplot` will put the legend with the larger limit range on the top. I was wonder if there was a way to fix the legend order so that, say `val1` is always on the top... no matter the range of the limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify the order of the legends via the `order` argument of `guide_xxx`:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = runif(10))
df_1 <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = runif(10))

pal_1 = rev(colorspace::sequential_hcl(palette = "Blues 3", n = 10))
pal_2 = rev(colorspace::sequential_hcl(palette = "Reds 3", n = 10))

library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(df, mapping = aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, aes(fill = y)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = pal_1, limits = c(0,1), name = "val1", 
                       guide = guide_colorbar(order = 1)) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_point(data = df_1, size = 3, aes(fill = y)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = pal_2, limits = c(0,10), name = "val2",
                       guide = guide_colorbar(order = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Great and easy answer